# How to troubleshoot Blender 2.83 crashing

Tags: performance

I’ve just added a GPU to my system in the last few days that has allowed me to upgrade from 2.79 to 2.83 YAY!!!

A few times while rendering though I return to my computer to finder Blender has shut down. One occasion I had 2 instances of 2.83 and one of 2.79 running at the same time (which might have been an issue) but on another 3 times it was only the rendering instance open.

Is there a way to find out when and why this might have happened?

I’m running Windows 7 (64 bit), 2nd Gen i5 3.3GHz, 12G RAM, GTX1650 (just installed). Everything seems to be running efficiently in task manager and I’m loving the new GPU and Blender version but I don’t want constant crashing and want to be able to avoid it becoming an ongoing problem if possible

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions here, you'll get a crash report:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/crash.html

It's no guaranteed fix, but it will get you some information. Also ofc. keep your drivers up to date.
And lastly, windows 7 isn't supported by MS anymore, seriously consider switching to win 10.